# Strange behavior with bsearch_index

Tags: ruby, bsearch

```
tmp = [-3,3,5]
p "test: #{tmp.bsearch_index{|j| j == -3}}"
```

In the above code, I get response as nil. If I compare j against 3, or 5, it works. Why does bsearch_index does not consider very first element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write

```
tmp.bsearch_index{|n| n >= -3}    #=> 0
```

This uses [Array#bsearch_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index)'s *find minimum* mode, which returns the smallest value in the array that satisfies the expression in the block. For example,

```
tmp.bsearch { |n| n >= 0 }        #=> 3
tmp.bsearch_index { |n| n >= 0 }  #=> 1
```

In this mode, to quote the doc for [Array#bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch), "the block must always return true or false, and there must be an index `i` (`0 <= i <= ary.size`) so that the block returns false for any element whose index is less than `i`, and the block returns true for any element whose index is greater than or equal to `i`. This method returns the `i`-th element. If `i` is equal to `ary.size`, it returns `nil`."

If the block were `{ |n| n == -3 }` there would be no index `i`, `0 <= i <= tmp.size #=> 3` that has the property that `tmp[j] == -3` is false for all `j < i` and true for all `j >= 1`.

If the block calculation were `tmp[j] == 5` the requirement would be satisfied (for index `2`) so the correct value would be returned. If the block calculation were `tmp[j] == 3` the requirement would not be satisfied (`tmp[2] == 3 #=> false`); the fact that the correct index is returned is only due to the way the method has been implemented. If

```
tmp = [-3, 3, 5, 6]
```

then `nil` is returned for `n == 3` as well as for `n == -3`:

```
tmp.bsearch_index { |n| n == 3 }  #=> nil
```

`bsearch` has a second mode, *find any* mode. (See the doc for `Array#bsearch` for details.) In this case we might write one of the following:

```
tmp.bsearch_index { |n| -3 - n }  #=> 0   
tmp.bsearch_index { |n|  3 - n }  #=> 1
tmp.bsearch_index { |n|  5 - n }  #=> 2
tmp.bsearch_index { |n|  4 - n }  #=> nil
```

This mode would be useful here if `nil` were to be returned when no element in the array evaluates to zero in the block. In other contexts it has a multitude of uses.

Comment: I kind of get it but don't get it. I understand the logic how it works after you quoted doc. I don't understand why would some one need to implement it that way? Binary search is a very common problem one could easily write a solution to accomodate == operator. What am I missing here?

Comment: Suppose you were to try to guess a number `n` between 0 and 99 and could ask questions of someone who knew the value of `n` who could answer only "yes" or "no". You might first ask if `n < 50`. If the answer were "yes", you might then ask if `n < 25`; else you might ask if `n < 75`, and so on. That's a binary search. But if you asked if `n == 50` and were told "no", you wouldn't know if `n < 50` or `n >50`, so that answer to your question would be insufficient to perform a binary search.

Comment: Or `tmp.bsearch_index { |n| -3 <=> n }` to find that specific element.

Comment: @Stefan, good point. I added a mention but just used `-3 - n`.